# What is the best word to translate «anomaly»?

Tags: single-word-requests, akademia-vortaro

Although the *[Akademia Vortaro](http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/akademia_vortaro/index.html)* suggests the word *[anomalio](http://vortaro.net/#anomalio)*, adopted since the *Dua Oficiala Aldono*, I see no mention of this word in the *Baza Radikaro Oficiala* nor in the website *[La bona lingvo](http://bonalingvo.net/index.php/%C4%88efpa%C4%9Do)*. I study health sciences, so I am more often exposed to the word *anomaly* than the general population, but in spite of that I do not think it is such a rare word in everyday life too. So shouldn't we be able to express the same idea with more common morphemes?

Answer (score 4):

"Anomalio" can be found in PIV. (http://vortaro.net/#anomalio)

"Escepto" and "Eksternormalajxo" are also mentioned there. Otherwise I would suggest  "nenormalajxo" or even "malnormalajxo".

Comment: I had linked to PIV in my question. I usually don't rely on it, since we can also find words such as [liva](http://vortaro.net/#liva) and [mava](http://vortaro.net/#mava) that are to be avoided as much as possible in my opinion. Are *nenormalaĵo* and *malnormalaĵo* synonymous? Is one better than the other?

Comment: Ops, missed that, sorry. Nenormala means "not normal". Malnorma menas "the opposite of normal". So they are not entierly the same. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean. To my understanding, being "not normal" is the opposite of being "normal". Either you follow the norm, either you don't. I don't see anything in-between. Do you have an example?

Comment: having a small, but visible, cut is not the "normal" state of human flesh (nenormala), but it is not "abnormal" either. Having a your limb cut off is "abnormal" (malnormala).

Answer (score 3):

If *anomalio* is in the *Akademia Vortaro*, I wouldn't doubt that it's usage is valid. However, I also understand your hesitation to use words that may not be readily understandable. I suggest *nenormalaĵo* as opposed to *malnormala*. Althought it is true that the two differ semantically in that *nenormala* is "not normal" and *malnormala* is "opposite of normal", in practice they seem to be the same. However, in every search, *nenormala* / *nenormalaĵo* is more common than *malnormala* / *malnormalaĵo*.

Searching on Google:

- *nenormalaĵo* trafficked 3,330 results, while *malnormalaĵo* trafficked  2,450
- *nenormala* trafficked 15,800 results, while *malnormala* trafficked only 
  5,680

Searching on Tekstaro:

- Neither *nenormalaĵo* nor *malnormalaĵo* trafficked any results in Tekstaro, which only indicates that it hasn't been used in the tracked literature.
- However *nenormala* trafficked 17 results, while *malnormala* trafficked only 
  3

This demonstrates that *nenormala* and *nenormalaĵo* are at least in mild use, and considering that anomaly is a synonym for irregularity or abnormality, and that the Greek word it is derived from has the same meaning, I'd concede that *anomalio* could be ceded to *nenormalaĵo*.